# How can I speed up a very large javascript HTML insertion in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have some javascript that generates a large set of HTML and then inserts it into a web page.

In Firefox the code runs almost instantaneously; but in Chrome, the code blocks the browser and takes approximately 10 seconds to complete.

How can I improve the user experience? I would like to either speed up the code in Chrome, or make the code not block so that I can display a spinner.

I've tried so many things I won't bother to list them all here.

[Here is a jsfiddle with a running, simplified example.](https://jsfiddle.net/hhjhkre7/3/)

And below is the code, minus the very large data array:

(Note that underscore.js is used for brevity)

```
var optionsHtml = _.map(data, function(value){
  return '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>';
}).join('');

var selectHtml = '<select multiple>' + optionsHtml + '</select>';

var fieldSet = document.getElementById('myid');

fieldSet.innerHTML = selectHtml;
```

Comment: It took 20 ms for me to run. I don't know if you can do it any better than how you are doing it. The one thing I am curious about is if you really want a select box with almost 5000 options?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm afraid of. And I do want all the 5000 options. I'm wrapping the select box in a [chosen.js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) element, so it is quite user friendly. I may have to approach the problem differently.

Comment: @David think you can do better using a simple text input with `autocomplete` feature instead of a huge `select`.

Comment: That is a great idea. Thanks, @FaresM.!